# ODP.Net, Entity Framework: ORA-00947 (not enough values) when trying to add a record with Store Generated Identity

Tags: vb.net, oracle, entity-framework

I have simple table where I want to insert new records.
The table has an ID column which is set as identity and generated always.
`StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity` is set for the ID column.

When I try to add a new record to the table in VB.Net

```
rec = New TEST_TABLE
ctx.TEST_TABLE.Add(rec)
ctx.SaveChanges()
```

It results in get ORA-00947: not enough values.
It seems as if the Entity Framework is creating an invalid SQL request. Something like `INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES('Tom');`.

How can I solve this situation?
How can I check, which SQL request is sent to Oracle?

Adding lines with direct sql queries works perfectly:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (NAME) VALUES('Tom');
1 line affected.
```

The table's schemata is as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEST_TABLE" 
   ("NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOORDER NOCYCLE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "TEST_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   );
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST_TABLE_PK" ON "TEST_TABLE" ("ID");
```

Edit: I solved the problem: `StoreGeneratedValue=Identity` was set for NAME, not for ID. After correcting this, everything just works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not enough values" comes when there are too few values passed on insert statement. Like this

```
insert into table_name(col1, col2, col3) values(1, 2)
```

I've passed 2 values whereas there are 3 columns listed in the beginning of insert. Thus, I almost sure, underlying insert statement lacks of a value.

You need to check content of inserting routine on VB side if posiible.

As a workaround I'd try to replace "GENERATED ALWAYS" with "GENERATED BY DEFAULT" and run the VB code with StoreGeneratedPattern=None

Comment: Hi @A.F. you need to examine the source of TEST_TABLE.Add(rec) and find out how you may exclude "ID" column from the underlying insert statement.I've updated my answer with some more explanation

Comment: With ``StoreGeneratedPattern=None``, I get ORA-32795. This error can be expected because the value for StoreGeneratedPattern is wrong. Setting ``StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity`` should solve this and exclude ID from the vb side. But with this setting, I get ORA-00947: not enough values. This is strange.

Comment: @A.F."Not enough values" comes when there are too few values passed on insert statement. Like this  "insert into table_name(col1, col2, col3) values(1, 2)" I've passed 2 values whereas there are 3 columns listed in the beginning of insert. Thus, I almost sure, underlying insert statement lacks of a value. As a workaround I'd try to replace "GENERATED ALWAYS" with "GENERATED BY DEFAULT" or check the Add routine that inserts data

Comment: Thank you @ekochergin for your answer. actually ORA-32795 is not my main problem, but ORA-00947. I think, I did not make this clear in my original question.

Comment: I solved the problem. I accidently set ``StoreGeneratedValue=Identity`` for NAME, not for ID. Thank you for your support!

Comment: @A.F. no probs. You're welcomw